# Comparision of an umlaut with literal fails

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains the single letter (german umlaut) Ä:

[image: Text file in Hex-Editor showing only the character Ä as 0xC4]

I'm reading this file in a script.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Test.txt' -Encoding 1252
```

When I write `$content` to the console, the Ä is displayed correctly. But when I'm doing a comparison with a literal it yields a wrong result.

```
if ($content -eq 'Ä')
{
    "Match"
}
else
{
    "No match"
}
```

Why does this print *No match*?

Comment: Try with `-Encoding UTF8` or `-Encoding Default`. It all depends on what encoding is used to save the text file and if that `Ä` character is the only text in it.

Comment: This doesn't help; with UTF8 `Get-Content` doesn't read anything from the file.

Comment: What kind of encoding is 1252? I tried it locally with UTF8 and it worked. 1252 does not even work for me, it throws an error.

Comment: What does `[int] $content[0]` give, and what does `[int] 'Ä'[0]` give? Take care to execute the latter in the context of your original statement (either a script, or else copy the literal exactly).

Comment: @Dugnom That's [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: @Dugnom: the ability to pass a code page to `-Encoding` was added in PowerShell 6.2. This won't work in prior versions of PowerShell.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `[int] $content[0]` gives 196, `[int] 'Ä'[0]` gives 65533.

Comment: @Dugnom `1252` is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (ANSI) but you cannot use it like the OP does in PowerShell. `Default` should do it, but if there is more text in the file then comparing a single character to the content with `-eq` will never work of course..

Comment: Well that's not right then, is it. Unsure how `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` ends up in there without being printed to the console -- actually, it *should* print to the console, you never tried that. :P If you're doing this inside a script, ensure your `.ps1` file is saved in a proper encoding (UTF-8 should work). Note how that encoding is separate from your input file encoding. If doing this from the command line, I'm not sure how encodings interact there. `chcp 65001`? `[Console]::InputEncoding`? It's a bit messy.

Comment: @JeroenMostert _ensure your .ps1 file is saved in a proper encoding (UTF-8 should work)_ That was the problem. My script file was indeed Windows-1252; saving it as UTF-8 resolved the issue.